Why 'nircmd exec hide application.exe' and any other way to hide an application doesn't work with Borland C++Builder applications?
Why nircmd exec hide application.exe and any other method doesn't work with Borland C++Builder applications?
Minimized works, but not hidden.
I tried any possible methods aside nircmd exec hide application.exe but nothing works.

I don't understand the question. What are you trying to hide, exactly? What else have you tried that is not working?  Please clarify the issue with more detail.

When you have an application that opens does something and then closes rapidly many times, you do not want to see the application open and close, open and close, open and close, so you want to hide it. Now, there is a software called nircmd, which run as "nircmd exec hide appname.exe" hide that application from view. nircmd and other methods to do that, you can search on google, do not work with any borland c++ build application and I just want to know if someone knows why. Have I been clear enough?

C++Builder (and Delphi) apps create a hidden "application" window that owns other visible windows. The "main" window that users see onscreen when the app starts is not the first window created, and so any request to start the app hidden is ignored since the "application" window is already hidden. Secondary windows don't care if the app was started hidden or not.
This "application" window is largely a legacy feature nowadays. Originally, it controlled the app's main Taskbar button (amongst other things), so that if the app creates multiple visible windows then they would not also create separate Taskbar buttons for them.  But, due to compatibility reasons in Vista onward, the default behavior has now been for the "main" window instead to control the Taskbar button. But the "application" window still exists.
Hiding/showing the "application" window has no effect on the app's other windows, but minimizing/maximizing the "application" window will in turn minimize/hide and maximize/show the other windows.
